# Group by and aggregate values from multiple time periods in python and pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe like below. We have data for each month.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
              'month': ['2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-04',
                        '2020-01','2020-02','2020-03','2020-04'],
              'amt': [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 5]})
```

```
    id  month   amt
0   A   2020-01 2
1   A   2020-02 3
2   A   2020-03 4
3   A   2020-04 5
4   B   2020-01 2
5   B   2020-02 3
6   B   2020-03 1
7   B   2020-04 5
```

I need to aggregate values from multiple months.  Below is the desired result.

```
    id  month_start month_end   amt
0   A   2020-01     2020-03     9
1   A   2020-02     2020-04     12
2   B   2020-01     2020-03     6
3   B   2020-02     2020-04     9
```

I'm looking for a general solution. The real case is more complicated. For example, there could be `n` months between start and end. Appreciate it if someone can find solution in both python and pyspark. Thanks.

Comment: what is your condition to generate start month and end month?

Comment: n consecutive months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pyspark you can use `collect_list` over a Window with frame boundaries specified as rows between `[-n, currentRow]`,
to get the `n` consecutive months and also calculate a running sum of `amt` over this same Window. Finally, filter only rows with size of months equals `n + 1`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

# create spark df from pandas dataframe
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

n = 2
w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("month").rowsBetween(-n, Window.currentRow)

result = sdf.withColumn("months", F.collect_list("month").over(w)) \
    .withColumn("amt", F.sum("amt").over(w)) \
    .filter(F.size("months") == n + 1) \
    .select(
        F.col("id"),
        F.element_at(F.col("months"), 1).alias("month_start"),
        F.element_at(F.col("months"), -1).alias("month_end"),
        F.col("amt")
    )

result.show()
#+---+-----------+---------+---+
#| id|month_start|month_end|amt|
#+---+-----------+---------+---+
#|  A|    2020-01|  2020-03|  9|
#|  A|    2020-02|  2020-04| 12|
#|  B|    2020-01|  2020-03|  6|
#|  B|    2020-02|  2020-04|  9|
#+---+-----------+---------+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

[`groupby_rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) would work well here. `groupby` "id" and create a rolling `n` window object. Then find sum of "amt" and find the first and last months of the rolling window. Note that since `rolling` doesn't accept non-numeric values, we need to use the `df.index` to filter the correct `start_month` and `end_month` dates for each rolling window.

```
n = 3
# index will be used to get the start and end months in rolling
df = df.reset_index()
r_obj = df.groupby('id').rolling(n)
out = r_obj['amt'].sum().dropna().droplevel(1).reset_index()
month_idx = r_obj['index'].agg({'start_month_idx': lambda x: x.iat[0], 'end_month_idx': lambda x: x.iat[-1]}).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
out['start_month'] = df.loc[month_idx['start_month_idx'], 'month'].reset_index(drop=True)
out['end_month'] = df.loc[month_idx['end_month_idx'], 'month'].reset_index(drop=True)
out = out[['id', 'start_month', 'end_month', 'amt']]
```

Output:

```
  id start_month end_month   amt
0  A     2020-01   2020-03   9.0
1  A     2020-02   2020-04  12.0
2  B     2020-01   2020-03   6.0
3  B     2020-02   2020-04   9.0
```

Comment: does anyone know how to do ```group by ('id').rolling(n)``` in pyspark?